# Change Jenkins concurrent job workspace naming

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, workspace

Can I change the way Jankins names the workspace for concurrent jobs?   Currently it uses the @2, @3 when running concurrent builds.  I would like to change the "@" to another character.  Is this possible.  It is causing problems further down in my jobs.

Workspace created for concurrent job #2:
in workspace /devsrc/jenkins/workspace/CKPT_vw5.2_ubuntu@2

Further down in build script:
The environment variable II_SYSTEM contains characters that are not
allowed. The path should only contain alphabetic, digit, period,
underscore and hyphen characters.
+ [ ! -f /devsrc/jenkins/workspace/CKPT_vw5.2_ubuntu@2/ingres/files/config.dat ]
+ exit 1

Answer (score 6):

I didn't test this before posting, but I've used these types of parameters in the past with no problems. See [features controlled by system properties](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Features+controlled+by+system+properties). In there, there's one to change the @ to something else:

> "hudson.slaves.WorkspaceList"  (default value: @)
>
> When concurrent builds is enabled, a unique workspace directory name is required for each concurrent build. To create this name, this token is placed between project name and a unique ID, e.g. "my-project@123".

In Ubuntu, I would edit /etc/default/jenkins and add this to the "JAVA_ARGS" property and say use "A" instead of "@". And of course you'll need to restart Jenkins.

```
-Dhudson.slaves.WorkspaceList=A
```